# pst-plots not displaying negative exponents

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to graph a piecewise function, with one component using negative exponents. However, pst-plots doesn't seem to understand the negative exponent. I've tried expressing it a few different ways, but it will either show nothing or plot something linear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
xunit=.8cm,
yunit=1cm,
}

\def\L{-.2}
\def\R{5}
\def\B{-0.2}
\def\T{3.2}

\def\dL{2pt}
\def\dR{12pt}
\def\dB{2pt}
\def\dT{18pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false]
(\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
(\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)
\psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)[$x$,0][$f(x)$,90]
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,plotpoints=2}
\psplot[arrows=-*]{\L}{1}{0}
\psplot[arrows=o-]{1}{\R}{3x^(-4)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am open to other methods of graphing it, but I like how pst-plots looks more so than other packages.

Edit:

I am trying to graph f(x) = 3*x^{-4} over (1,\infty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the option `plotpoints=2`, you can hope but for a line. The default is 50! I suggest you set `plotstyle=curve` instead, and of course add `*` as already pointed. The `showgrid=false` option is useless, as it is the default. You can compile adding the `pdf` option to the document class: it will be passed on to `pstricks` that will launch `epstopdf`(provided the `--shell-escape` option be enabled) and the resulting .pdf image will be cropped.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
xunit=.8cm,
yunit=1cm,
}

\def\L{-.2}
\def\R{5}
\def\B{-0.2}
\def\T{3.2}

\def\dL{2pt}
\def\dR{12pt}
\def\dB{2pt}
\def\dT{18pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false]
(\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
(\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)
\psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)[$x$,0][$f(x)$,90]
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,plotstyle = curve}
\psplot[arrows=-*]{\L}{1}{0}
\psplot[arrows=o-]{1}{\R}{3*x^(-4)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, silly mistake on my part. I'm still getting used to the package so thank you very much for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is `3*x^(-x)`. You forgot the `*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{xunit=.8cm,yunit=1cm}

\def\f(x){3*x^(-4)}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(6,3.5)
\psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-0.2)(5.5,3.2)[$x$,0][$f(x)$,90]
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
\psplot[arrows=*-,plotpoints=100]{1}{5}{3*x^(-4)}
\psplot[arrows=-o,plotpoints=2]{-0.2}{1}{0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood. I do NOT want something linear. I want to plot the function f(x) = 3x^{-4} over the interval (1,infinity).

Comment: Ok, then do _not_  choose `plotpoints=2`. It is obvious that you do get a linear curve with only two points.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that was the purpose of that function. Your answer makes much more sense now that I realize my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just another new template from me.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0bp,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\XMin{-1}
\FPset\XMax{4}
\FPset\YMin{0}
\FPset\YMax{3}

\FPset\DeltaX{1}
\FPset\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\Left{XMin-DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Right{XMax+DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Bottom{YMin-DeltaY/4}
\FPeval\Top{YMax+DeltaY/4}

\newlength\Width\Width=10cm
\newlength\Height\Height=6cm

\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt
\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt



\psset
{
    algebraic,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    plotpoints=80,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    tickcolor=gray,
    ticksize=0 -4pt,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
}



\def\f{0}
\def\g{1}
\def\h{3/x^4}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[dx=\DeltaX,dy=\DeltaY,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psset{linecolor=NavyBlue,linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \psplot[arrows=-o]{\XMin}{1}{\f}
    \psplot[arrows=*-*]{1}{1}{\g}
    \psplot[arrows=o-]{1}{\XMax}{\h}
    \rput[tr](\Right,\Top){$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &;\, x<1\\ 1 &;\, x=1\\ 3/x^4 &;\, x>1\end{cases}$}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

The arrow `-o` or `o-` is unfortunately a function of `plotpoints`. The  result can not be guaranteed to be correct for any value of `plotponts` for sure. In other words, higher `plotpoints` does not guarantee that you will get a correct arrow.